# No Lava in my Pressure Cooked Lava Cake!

Tags: pressure-cooker

I tried a youtube recipe for making lava cake in a pressure cooker. It really turned out very good except there was no lava, just cake. I think it was because I over cooked it. I'm not really sure. I preheated the water and then proceeded to pressure cook. I only pressure cooked for 5 minutes because it took 5-10 minutes to build the pressure.

Comment: Please always add a link to the recipe you were using (better: write it in your post).

Answer (score 3):

For lava cake, cooked using any method, there is a relatively fine line between perfect and over cooked.  It appears that you crossed that line.